# how to mask AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in gitlab-ci

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my Gitlab CI, I need to push a docker image to AWS ECR, so I need `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

In Gitlab, when I go in Settings > CI / CD > Variables, I can put my variables, but I won't be able to mask `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as stated in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variables):

> The value must be in a single line.
>   The value must not have escape characters.
>   The value must not use variables. 
>   The value must not have any whitespace. 
>   The value must be at least 8 characters long.

The SECRET has a format like `xXxxX/lX+KgoS70+wZzzZz` which doesn't pass the second criteria, so, I won't be able to mask the variables in logs, which is a serious security issue.

Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was to tell you to encode `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` in base64 but it doesn't work either for the same reason.

A workaround is described on gitlab [forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/this-variable-will-not-be-masked-for-aws-secret-access-key/25723/2) for the same use case :

```
echo xXxxX/lX+KgoS70+wZzzZz | base64 -d | base32
```

An issue has been [opened](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60790) requesting to allow more special characters in masked variables.

**Edit** : it's now [fixed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variables) in Gitlab 12.2, `@` and `:` are also valid values.

Comment: what if there is % or # character in the string? For me its not working.

````root@agg-2:~# echo hkhjjh%Ywehhbbkjyj | base64 -d | base32````


````OUTPUT ====> base64: invalid input
QZEGHDQ=
root@agg-2:~#````

Answer (score 1):

With GitLab 12.10, April 2020, this should be easier, both because:

- the  Base64 alphabet (RFC4648) has been extended to accept `@` and `:` (GitLab 12.2 as noted by Nicolas)
- the AWS variables are listed in the UI so you can choose them more quickly.

> ### [Easy to configure AWS deployment variables](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/04/22/gitlab-12-10-released/#easy-to-configure-aws-deployment-variables)
>
> When deploying to AWS, applying the necessary environment variables should be as convenient as possible, and are validated.
>
> You can now select the predefined variables for ‘AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID’, ‘AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY’ and ‘AWS_DEFAULT_REGION’ from the environment variable key list.
>
> You’ll also see the variables you enter validated to ensure they are entered in a valid format.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_10/aws_var.png]